# Sub application in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

Currently I have a website built with Umbraco 4.9.

What are the options to have a sub application (pure MVC 4 preferably) running under Umbraco infrastructure?

The idea is to have a custom app with custom database and custom logic. The only integration points would be:

- common user base (authentication)
- access to Umbraco's dictionaries from custom app
- share same session, that is if user is navigating through pages in
  custom app his session should not expire for website
- have custom app
  under same domain (*www.mysite.com* for website and *www.mysite.com/app*
  for app)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: @Douglas: IIS 8 for development, Windows Azure Website for production is planned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with v4.0.9, but I imagine its somewhat similar to 4.7. If that's the case, you should be fine to place your sub application inside the folder structure of your existing umrbaco instance. In IIS, you will need to convert the subfolder into an application. Within the web.config of your umbraco instance, you will need to add the path to your sub app in the `umbracoReservedPaths` app setting.

I'm not sure how session would here. I believe the asp.net membership should work fine. By adding references to the Umbraco dll's in your mvc project you should be able to access the Umbraco dictionaries fine.

Comment: Oh my, sorry for a stupid mistake - it's version 4.9. Question corrected

Comment: Oh okay, my answer should still apply then.

Comment: It will take me some time to test that. Will be back as soon as I have results

Comment: Had too little time to spend on this (and I think I will not work on it any more). It *looks* like your suggestion is plausible (found some similar suggestions on a web), but I did not manage to setup web.config for inner project (too many settings are inherited from Umbraco parent project's web.config). Moreover this project got suspended so I cannot state that this would work 100%. But you were the only one to try to help me - thanks a lot.